# how much is it secure to share login data using java-bean using socket

Tags: java, network-programming, javabeans

I want to build a chat Server and client using sockets.
For this first i want to be user login.
I have created a java-bean class and i want to know 
How much it is secure to send this java-bean containing username ,email and  password to server ?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide a meaningful answer. You could start by describing what you're using (jdk apis, frameworks, etc.), and post some code?

Comment: i am using jdk and simple sockets
I am using java beans class it's also in plain text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use an SSLSocket, its not secure at all. Also it is really not clear what you mean by sending a java bean (Spring, EJB...).

Comment: SSLSocket is more secure or Encryption is more secure ?

Comment: That can't be answered generally. But the simpler solution would be using SSLSockets (which requires you to create a certificate!). That way, there's no need to encrypt/decrypt the content you send over the network "manually".